# Given a solution, find a diff equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

i got following question during exam: 
$$
(E): (Cx\ln (x)-1)e^{0.5x^2}
$$
Given (E), find a first order differential equation which allows (E) as solution.
Here is what I have tried. Since we have

$ y'+a(x)y = b(x)$ this leads to  $ y= Ke^{-\int a(x)dx}=Ke^{u(x)}$

Thus, if I suppose that (E) is a sum of $y_h=Cx\ln (x) e^{0.5x^2} $ and $y_p=-e^{0.5x^2}$, this leads me to: $u(x)= e^{0.5x^2}Cx \ln (x)$.

$u'(x) = x\ln(x\ln(x)) + \frac{x(\ln(x)+1)}{2\ln(x)}= -a(x) $

I stopped at this point since I felt incomfortable with all these logs of logs, I guess there must be a better way...How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Taking the derivative you can quickly see that
$$
y' - yx = Ce^{x^2/2}
$$

Comment: -_- Thank you but I couldn't quickly see that... SUppose this shortuct didnt exist, what's wrong with my solution? Why I am not getting this simple answer

Comment: I strongly suspect the differential equation intended was not supposed to include $C$ as a parameter; that $C$ came out as a constant of integration.

Answer (score 0):

Expressing the constant from the solution, we get $\frac{1+ue^{-x^2/2}}{x\ln x}=C.$ Differentiation will destroy the constant:
$$(u'-ux)e^{-x^2/2}x\ln x-(1+ue^{-x^2/2})(\ln x+1)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your derivation. Where you have $u(x) = x\ln (x)\,e^{x^2/2}$, it should be $e^{u(x)} = x\ln (x)\,e^{x^2/2}$. This gives
$$
a(x) = -\frac{x^2+1}{x} - \frac{1}{x\ln(x)}
$$
From which you can find $b(x)$ through simple differentiation.

Also part of me is now curious if there's a nonlinear differential equation with this solution that has simpler coefficients.